# Which one is better for low end pc?

Tags: xorg, kde, desktop-environments, wayland

I just want to know which desktop environment is better for my pc.\

> Kde plasma or Ubuntu xorg or Ubuntu wayland

I am so confused on searching on internet.
And I also want good gui based linux because i am new to it. 
Here,are my computer specs: 
**Hp probook 4420s of 2gb ram ,intel core i5 4 cores 2.4Ghz variant**

And currently using Ubuntu 22.04LTS

Comment: I think Xubutnu is optimal.

Comment: I already tried Xubuntu 22 environment,  but thats also takes as much ram as ubuntu 22

Comment: You can try a lightweight OS like Linux Lite or MX Linux (they are not official flavors of Ubuntu). However, if you can, consider upgrading the amount of RAM.

Comment: Since, I also want a better community like this to ask about its bugs

Comment: Thanks for help Artur

Comment: And others also

Comment: @Levente Source? [Last time I checked](https://www.forbes.com/sites/jasonevangelho/2019/10/23/bold-prediction-kde-will-steal-the-lightweight-linux-desktop-crown-in-2020/), KDE Plasma was among the more light-weight DEs, comparable with Xfce.

Comment: For the cost of a little time you can try several. Download ISO and create live installer and see how well it works. Writing & loading from USB flash drive will be slower than when installed, but once loaded into RAM, it is all the same. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie I was able to load 20.04 Kubuntu into my 2006 laptop with only 1.5GB of RAM. I was surprised it worked as it is more of a mid-weight flavor. Ubuntu would not even load, server also installed, and I added a lightweight gui.

Comment: @lemontree "_When I say 'Xfce,' it’s a good bet you think about a lean, responsive Linux desktop environment that’s particularly light on system memory usage. And you’d be absolutely right. Does that same description dance through your head when I say 'KDE?' If not, one can hardly blame you. KDE seems to be perceived as a 'bloated' but beautiful desktop environment. If you hold that belief, I’m here to tell you it’s time to change your opinion._" TIL, THNX.

Answer (score 2):

If your computer has only 2 GB of RAM I think both Gnome and KDE are not very appropiate.

If you want to install a very recent version of Ubuntu I would try LXQT, default desktop environment of Lubuntu.

You can install an older version of Ubuntu too. Now with Canonical free offer of [Ubuntu pro](https://ubuntu.com/pro) you get 10 years of security updates. I say that because Ubuntu 18.04 came with LXDE desktop environment which is even lighter than LXQT.

But depending of how you use your PC, LXQT could be light enough and you get a more recent version of software packages. You may have to go through a trial and error process.

You also have to consider that the main consumer of resources is the browser. Among the DEs there may be differences of consideration between those who consume more like Gnome and KDE and those who consume less. So maybe you don't find much difference between LXDE, LXQT and even XFCE (default in Xubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

You are conflating two different things here: The desktop environment (e.g. Gnome or KDE Plasma), and the graphics platform (X11 or Wayland).   You use a desktop environment together with a graphics platform.

You can use either of standard Ubuntu (= Ubuntu with Gnome), Kubuntu (= Ubuntu with KDE Plasma) with X11 or with Wayland.

If you're on older hardware, KDE Plasma and X11 are probably the safer choice. KDE Plasma because it is more leightweight than Gnome, and X11 because it has been around for longer and supports more older hardware than Wayland.

Comment: I believe what you refer to as "graphics platform" is called a "[display server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windowing_system#Display_server)" (I must confess, up to today I called them display managers.)

Comment: @Levente "Graphics platform" is how KDE's system information page calls it. "Display server" I think technically refers to the server (Xorg) that implements the protocol (X11), and what is typically meant by a "display manager" is what could also be described as a "login manager" with one example being SDDM. But I don't care much about the nitpicking.

Comment: Ok, I understand.Thanks for reply